# XCUITest Simulator architecture appears to be unsupported by the Appium1.13.0

Tags: ios, automation, appium, xcuitest

I am trying to test native iOS app using Appium v1.13.0.

When I execute the tests using iOS Simulator lunched by 
Xcode 10.2, I get the following error from the Appium server.

```
*********************************
*********************************
[XCUITest] Verifying application platform
[XCUITest] CFBundleSupportedPlatforms: ["iPhoneOS"]
[XCUITest] *********************************
[XCUITest] Simulator architecture appears to be unsupported by the '/var/folders/ld/f5b4gf396332hxdc9tw6kyrc0000gn/T/2019512-62665-1x5tail.vqbi/Payload/*****.app' application. Make sure the correct deployment target has been selected for its compilation in Xcode.
[XCUITest] Don't be surprised if the application fails to launch.
[XCUITest] *********************************
[XCUITest] Reset requested. Removing app with id 'com.*****.mp' from the device
[XCUITest] Installing '/var/folders/ld/f5b4gf396332hxdc9tw6kyrc0000gn/T/2019512-62665-1x5tail.vqbi/Payload/*****.app' on Simulator with UUID '204794D9-CA97-479C-B004-8DBC04942CF5'...
[XCUITest] The app has been installed successfully.
[BaseDriver] Event 'appInstalled' logged at 1560335980109 (13:39:40 GMT+0300 (EEST))
*********************************
*********************************
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your application has been built for `iPhoneOS` platform only, you will not be able to run it in the Simulator as the simulator assumes different architecture ([x86](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86)) while real iOS devices run on [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)

You need to execute [xcodebuild](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) command and specify `iOS Simulator` platform as the output target like:

```
xcodebuild build -workspace "*****.xcworkspace" -scheme "*****" -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone SE" -configuration Release
```

If you don't have access to the application sources - unfortunately you will be only able to test it using real iOS devices, check out [Appium XCUITest Driver Real Device Setup](http://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/) article for the required steps (by the way, the processes of generating/managing provisioning profiles and Simulators/devices are much easier with the [Appium Studio](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/))

Comment: I got the following error when executing the command

The following build commands failed:
 CompileSwift normal x86_64
 CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
(2 failures)

Comment: Thank you. It works but how can I export IPA file not .app